# Please help! I have a problem with getting wordpress databas

Tags: php, database, mysql

The file path is:
wordpress/​wp-content/​themes/​neve/​index.php

"index.php" content is:

```php
<?php
global $wpdb;
$result = $wpdb->get_results ( "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = 'Peter'");
foreach ( $result as $results )
{
    echo $results->id.'<br/>';
    echo $results->username.'<br/>';
    echo $results->password.'<br/>';
}
?>
```

It works!
But, when I change the content of the index.php, see below:
New "index.php" content is:

```php
<?php
header("Location: http://34.92.209.11/wp-content/themes/neve/Test_PHP.php");
?>
```

Then the content of the "Test_PHP.php" is:

```php
<?php
global $wpdb;
$result = $wpdb->get_results ( "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = 'Peter'");
foreach ( $result as $results )
{
    echo $results->id.'<br/>';
    echo $results->username.'<br/>';
    echo $results->password.'<br/>';
}
?>
```

It does not work, and shows "HTTP ERROR 500", why???
Only the file name called "index.php" can access the database?
I've been trying to find the answer.
I really hope someone can answer me.
Thank you so much!

Comment: Is this the full contents of the files? Is there a reference to `get_header()` which would contain `wp_head()` to give you access to `$wpdb`? Could you remove the image and add in actual, workable code, please?

Comment: I've edited your question to restore the original edit and then wrapped the code in code blocks as there was no formatting. Do not upload images of text

Answer (score 0):

In [WordPress's template hierarchy](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-hierarchy/), `index.php` is the catch-all file for any WordPress post/page/archive/etc. that might get loaded. By the time the active theme's `index.php` file is loaded, WordPress is already set up.

By redirecting from the theme's `index.php` to another file, you're re-starting the page load from scratch. If you don't explicitly include certain WordPress files, then there are no WordPress functions, classes, etc. that will be loaded.

`$wpdb`, in that case, is unset (`NULL`, most likely), and your 500 error is most likely because you're trying to treat an unset `NULL` value like an object.